# Accessing helper method in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a helper method in my Application Controller that i need to use in a Model (but it should obviously also be available to my View). From what i'm reading this is something that should be avoided as the model shouldn't be able to see anything in the controller. So it seems i need to refactor my code or create a module or something but i don't know what the right thing to do is?

This is my helper method in the Application Controller:

```
def total_price

Product.where(id: basket.to_a).sum(:price)

end
```

Many Thanks

Comment: Move your helper method in Your helper files.

Comment: Do you mean put the helper method in application_helper.rb? Will it still be available to the View?

Comment: yes..but as its related to model only so it must be moved to model like in @Rafael's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you refactor it to a model class method, like this:

```
class Product

  def self.total_basket_price(basket)
    where(id: basket.to_a).sum(:price)
  end

end
```

Then you can use it in your models as well as in your controllers and views, just calling:

```
Product.total_basket_price(basket)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: wow, than you so much, i'm going to spend some time understanding what you did but it has worked great!

Comment: would you be able to explain the method? I don't understand what 'def self.total_basket_price(basket)' is doing?

Comment: @James You should learn class, methods(instance and class methods). Do some reading on ruby basics.

Comment: Hi James. The main concept here is the "class method". Class methods are methods that can be called in a class without having an instance of it. An example of it is the `where` method that you call using `Product.where(...)`. We just created another class method (for that we use "self." before the method name. This method can be used also without having a instance of product created.

Comment: Great, i think the bit i'm unsure of is the (basket) argument. I didn't think that 'basket' would be available in the Product model as it is a helper defined in the application controller?

Comment: It isn't available on the model! That's why you have to pass it as an argument. The method in the Product model just know that it's going to receive an array of ids and it has to sum the prices, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

add following in your model

```
    module Helper
        extend ActionView::Helpers
        extend YourModelHelper
      end
```

and access with `Helper.any_method`